# Generate PDF from java code that dynamically continue file template with iText

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I need to generate a pdf report with complex template. I have an xls file with a
complex layout that generally consists of a header with table header, table
rows, table footer and a general footer.

Is it possible to generate a pdf report with itext which would be
sequentially generated from

- Header.pdf file with the table's column headers row
- Dynamically generated in java code table row that would seamlessly continue
  the table from the Header.pdf
- Footer.pdf with column footers that would seamlessly continue table rows
  generated from java code.

Like this:

Header.pdf
`+----------------------------------------------+ 
 |                                              | 
 |                Header                        | 
 +----------------------------------------------+ 
 |                      |                       | 
 |   Column 1 Header    |     Column N Header   | 
 |                      |                       | 
 +----------------------------------------------+`

Java-code-generated table rows
 `+----------------------------------------------+
  |                      |                       |
  |      Value 11        |     Value 1M          |
  |                      |                       |
  +----------------------------------------------+
  ...
  +----------------------------------------------+
  |                      |                       |
  |     Value N1         |     Value NM          |
  |                      |                       |
  +----------------------+-----------------------+`

Footer.pdf
`+----------------------------------------------+
 |                      |                       |
 |   Column 1 Footer    |     Column N Footer   |
 |                      |                       |
 |                      |                       |
 +----------------------+-----------------------+
 |                                              |
 |                Footer                        |
 |                                              |
 +----------------------------------------------+`

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Here's the template in Excel.

The two rows of the table are straight in the middle of the template. And accordingly the general header with table column headers and the footer with column footers.

[image: The template]
[The template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzte3d6p2lrf2tm/Screenshot%202015-04-20%2019.28.44.png?dl=0)

Comment: Please describe header.pdf and footer.pdf. Why are it PDF files? Why not just some content? Why are it PDFs? What is the page size of these 1-page PDFs (assuming that they only have 1 page)? Are header.pdf and footer.pdf interactive PDFs or just flat?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie please see the update of the original post. I've made the screenshot of the source excel file.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the excel file. I don't see any header of footer, nor how this would relate to PDF. I'll show you an example and then you can use that example to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Did my answer correspond with the question?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you have a header ([header.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/header.pdf)) and a footer ([footer.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/footer.pdf)), then you can integrate these static PDFs as a header and a footer as described in the `SimpleTable8` example (see [simple_table8.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/simple_table8.pdf)):

[image]

[image]

Let's take a look at the code:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("resources/pdfs/header.pdf");
    PdfImportedPage header = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(header));
    cell.setColspan(3);
    table.addCell(cell);
    for (int row = 1; row <= 50; row++) {
        for (int column = 1; column <= 3; column++) {
            table.addCell(String.format("row %s, column %s", row, column));
        }
    }
    reader = new PdfReader("resources/pdfs/footer.pdf");
    PdfImportedPage footer = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
    cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(footer));
    cell.setColspan(3);
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

We import a header (or footer) like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("resources/pdfs/header.pdf");
PdfImportedPage header = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
```

Now we create a `PdfPCell` that wraps this `PdfImportedPage` inside an `Image` and we add the `cell` to the `table`:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(header));
cell.setColspan(3);
table.addCell(cell);
```

Note that wrapping the `PdfImportedPage` inside an `Image` doesn't rasterize the text. You'll discover that the text "This is a header" can still be selected, copied and pasted.